# Unable to upload file on amazon s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have given all s3 access to lambda to upload file on s3. There is no error and no response from aws.All the permission are given.

```
    var params4 = {
        Bucket: "bcket name",
        Key         : "tt.pdf",
        Body        : buf,
        ContentType : 'application/pdf',
        ACL       : 'public-read',
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    }
                                        
    var data1= s3.putObject(params4, function(err, data){
     console.log("successful");
     if (err) { 
      console.log("putobbject="+err);   
     }else{
      console.log(data);
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the 'aws-sdk' node package, right?

This is the code I'm using. The file type should be detected automatically. I used it for CSV and JSON so far but should work fine for PDF as well.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const uploadFile = (localFile, s3File, bucket) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY } = process.env;
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY
        });
        const loadedFile = fs.readFileSync(localFile);
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: s3File,
            Body: loadedFile
        };

        return s3.upload(params, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }

            return resolve(true);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = uploadFile;
```